# How do i load a secondary img when the first one does not load with php

Tags: php

I try to load a other img when the first one is not loading.

```
<?php
$id2 = intval($_GET['id']);
$jpg = ".jpg";
$id = $id2 . $jpg;

$imagepath= $id;
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg( $imagepath);


header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

this loads my img when i have the id in /img

now i want to load a img with the same id when `$imgsize = filesize( $id );` is 0.

from a external link like: http://xxxx.xx/getimg.php?id=28771

it should be easy with if else but i can't get it.

edit:

```
$id2 = intval($_GET['id']);
$jpg = ".jpg";
$id = $path . $id2 . $jpg;
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!=0){
    $id2 = intval($_GET['id']);
}
else{
    $id2 = 1;
}

$imagepath= $id;
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg( $imagepath);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
```

so this is the code I use now.

Comment: use a default image and store it at the path. Check `isset($_GET['id'])` and if no value in `$_GET['id']` than assign the value of default image path.

Comment: not sure how, will try, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this considering that `1.jpg` is a default file in your imagepath folder

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!=0){
    $id2 = intval($_GET['id']);
}
else{
    $id2 = 1;
}
?>
```

Something like this might solve your problem.This is just and idea you can modify the loops as per your need but i hope you got the overall idea.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!=0){ 
   $id2 = intval($_GET['id']); 
 } else{ 
   $id2 = 1; 
 } 

$jpg = ".jpg"; 
$id = $path . $id2 . $jpg;
$imagepath= $id; 
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg( $imagepath); 
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
imagejpeg($image);
```

Use this code and tell me if it works or not

Comment: Hei thank you, not sure why this is not working

$id2 = intval($_GET['id']);
$jpg = ".jpg";
$id = $path . $id2 . $jpg;
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!=0){
    $id2 = intval($_GET['id']);
}
else{
    $id2 = 1;
}

$imagepath= $id;
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg( $imagepath);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);

thats my code. It loads everypic with the id just fine but when i put in a id wich i don't have a pic of it loads nothing.

Thank you

Comment: @user1723097 can you please add this code into your question. And add if you are getting any error. Try to `echo` out the value of variable at every steps and post it as well to help understand your problem more.

Comment: @user1723097 not a problem. Glad i could help

Comment: so i should be able to input any id like http://rrario.hostzi.com/RXTS/img/getimg.php?id=123
and get 1.jpg? i asked the wrong way sorry... i don't want to load 1.jpg on id=0 i want to load a image from different directory with the same id when there is no image to load

Comment: @user1723097 so you can check the value of `$image` and do the same. Check if the value of `$image` is empty or not and if its empty than give the default path or any other path from where you want to get the image.

Comment: like this? if ( 0 == filesize( $image ) )
{
 $id = "$path$id";
}else{
 imagejpeg($image);
}
$path = "http://upload.happyfor.me/getimg.php?id=";
$id2 = intval($_GET['id']);
$jpg = ".jpg"; 
$id = $id2 . $jpg;
$imagepath= $id; 
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg( $imagepath);

Comment: @user1723097 edit the question and add this code in the question as it will be easy for me to understand it. And if possible place echo statement for all the variables like image and imagepath and also post the values if possible

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is in Javascript, there might be some scenarios where `$_GET['id']` is set but the actual image is missing. This uses jquery.

```
$('img').error(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("optional_class")) {
    $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "/no-picture.jpg");
  } else {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```